# Issue with CreateView ,object not created in model on submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have issue might missed something , i have created CreateView view for submitting objects in db , all seems to ok , but when i try to submit i don't get anything happen no error  at all except

> "POST /create_task/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12972 ,

MY code goes as follows , please advice

Thanks

models.py

```
class MainTask(models.Model):
task_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
global_task_info = models.TextField(max_length=500,default=None) 
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
overall_precent_complete = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
task_location = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)

global_task_assign = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="global_task_assign",default=1)
TASK_STATUS_CHOICES = [
('ST', 'STARTED'),
('NS', 'NOT STARTED'),
('IP', 'IN PROGRESS'),
('PA', 'PAUSED'),
('CO', 'COMPLETED'),
]
task_status = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=TASK_STATUS_CHOICES,default='NOT STARTED')

def __str__(self):
    return self.task_title
```

forms.py

```
class TaskCraetionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    TASK_STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('ST', 'STARTED'),
    ('NS', 'NOT STARTED'),
    ('IP', 'IN PROGRESS'),
    ('PA', 'PAUSED'),
    ('CO', 'COMPLETED'),
    ]


    task_title = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Task Title'}))
    global_task_info = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Task Description'}))
    due_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'picker'
        }))
    global_task_assign = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= UserProfile.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'} ))
    task_status = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=TASK_STATUS_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MainTask
        fields = ['task_title',
            'global_task_info',
            'due_date',
            'global_task_assign',
            'task_status',

        ]
```

views.py

```
class CreatTaskView(CreateView):
    model = MainTask

    template_name = "create_newtask.html"
    form_class = TaskCraetionForm
    success_url = None


    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)

        f.save()
        return super(CreatTaskView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: `200` in the logs suggests that the form data was invalid. Make sure you include `{{ form.errors }}` in the template so you can see what the problem is. If that doesn't work, then [edit] your question and include the template.

Comment: As an aside, setting `success_url = None` will not work. It should be something like `success_url = '/success/'`

Comment: Some comments on your code: 1. Your form doesn't include all fields required to create a `MainTask`, so it will raise an error when saving. 2. Almost certainly you have an error in one of your form fields so your template is rendered again. You need to add `{{ form.errors }}` in your template or `{{ form.some_field.errors }}` for each field.

Comment: 3. Your form contains a lot of redundant code. If you just need to override the widgets for your fields, all you need to do is define `widgets = {'some_field': <widget>}` in `Meta` as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields). 4. Your `form_valid()` in the `CreateView` is saving the form twice because you're saving it yourself and it's already being save in `super().form_valid()`. Remove `form_valid()` altogether as it doesn't do anything the default `form_valid()` doesn't do already.

Comment: Thank you very much you're comment gave me the direction and more

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much  Alasdair you're comment gave me the direction and more added the following to my HTML template shown below and found out i have issue with my datetime picker format needed to added the following
Thanks

```
INPUTֹTIMEֹFORMATS = [
'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M']
due_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=INPUTֹTIMEֹFORMATS, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'picker'
        }))
```

html temaplate

```
    <form action="" method="POST">

      <h3 class="mt-3 text-left">Create New Task</h3>
      <hr>
                <p class="text-muted text-left">Creat New Itom task</p>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.errors %}
        <!-- Error messaging -->
        <div id="errors">
            <div class="inner">
                <p>There were some errors in the information you entered. Please correct the following:</p>
                <ul>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% if field.errors %}<li>{{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>{% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Error messaging -->
    {% endif %}
        <div class="input-group mt-3 mb-3 mr-auto">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-book-medical"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{ form.task_title}}
          </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
        </div>
        {{form.global_task_info}}
      </div>

     <!---date time picker-->
     <h6 class="text-left">Task Due Date</h6>
     <div class="input-group date mb-3 col-3">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
      {{ form.due_date }}

    </div> 
    <!--end of date time picker-->
    <!---user assign-->
     <h6 class="text-left">Assign  Task to IT member</h6>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3 col-8">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>


          {{form.global_task_assign}}

      </div>
    </div>

   <!--End Of User Assign-->
   <h6 class="text-left">Set Task Status</h6>
   <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3 col-4">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">

        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-caret-square-right"></i></div>
    </div>
      {{form.task_status}}

    </div>

    <div class="col text-left">
    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-white mt-2"><span><i class="fas fa-database"></i></span> Create Task</button>
  </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```